# Executing python script that uses PyAudio in a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, python-3.x, audio-recording, pyaudio

I have a python script which uses pyaudio to record audio using microphone and the code converts speech to text.It works perfectly fine on terminal. Here is a section of the python code :

```
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)


async def send_audio(ws):
    # Starts recording of microphone
    print("* READY *")
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        try:
            #print(".")
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            await ws.send(data)
            ##if time.time() - start > 30:    # Records for n seconds
                ##await ws.send(json.dumps({'action': 'stop'}))
                ##return False
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
        except KeyboardInterrupt:  # allow Ctrl + C to shut down the program
            await ws.send(json.dumps({'action': 'stop'}))
            return False

    # Stop the stream and terminate the recording
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()


async def speech_to_text():
    async with websockets.connect(url, extra_headers=token_header) as conn:
        # Send request to watson and waits for the listening response
        send = await conn.send(json.dumps(params))
        rec = await conn.recv()
        print(rec)
        asyncio.ensure_future(send_audio(conn))
        w=0
        global lst
        # Keeps receiving transcript until we have the final transcript
        while True:
            try:
                rec = await conn.recv()
                parsed = json.loads(rec)
                transcript = parsed["results"][0]["alternatives"][0]["transcript"]

                #print(parsed)
                if "results" in parsed:
                    if len(parsed["results"]) > 0:
                        if "final" in parsed["results"][0]:
                            if parsed["results"][0]["final"]:
                                #conn.close()
                                #return False
                                print(transcript)
                                lst.append(transcript)
                                lst.append("\n")
                                pass
            except KeyError:
                conn.close()
                return False

# Starts the application loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(speech_to_text())
loop.close()
```

Now, I want to call this script in a web page by clicking a button. I tried using `exec()` and `shell_exec()` in php as:

```
<div>
    <?php
        echo "<h3>POST:</h3>";
        print_r($_POST);
        if (true) {} (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            print_r (shell_exec("cd / && python C:/xampp/htdocs/heyy/postibm.py"));
        }
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="try.php">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

But on clicking the button, the page is stuck on loading screen and gives no response. If I replace `postibm.py` with simple `helloworld.py` printing hello world, it works.

Comment: _"it didn't work"_ is a pretty poor explanation. What exactly happened? Error message? Show us what you tried and explain properly what happens.

Comment: exec() and shell_exec() should work just fine. Please post your code. Maybe you don't have enough permissions to execute applications on the server

Comment: edited..Check if it clarifies my doubt?